# Restarting Flask Application via Button

Tags: python, html, flask, restart

Is there a way that allows a user click on a button (on the HTML side) to trigger some event that restarts the entire Flask application? I am looking for an equivalent to terminating the program and then typing "Flask run" again. This seems like a simple problem and I have searched a bunch for it, but the only things I find are related to reloading/refreshing which are not really what I am going for.

HTML might be something like:

```
   <form action="/restart_function" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Restart App">
   </form>
```

Python might be something like:

```
  @app.route('/restart_function', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def restart():  
  .....
  return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can execute commands in the following ways:

with **subprocess**:

```
import subprocess

list_files = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

with **os.system**:

```
import os

home_dir = os.system("cd ~")
print("`cd ~` ran with exit code %d" % home_dir)
```

So if you want to restart your application, inside the function that handle your request, run the command to restart your application.

To prevent the http call from returning an error, handle the call by spawning a separate process that executes the command, so as to be able to complete the request while restarting the application. Obviously, if other http calls arrive in the meantime, those will not be successful since the application will be restarted.